# Azure Function - Time Trigger Function Status

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to ask you if it is possible to check current trigger function status (such as pending, working, succeed etc.) using InvocationId from ExecutionContext?

My current code:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ServiceFunction))]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 5 9 * * *")] TimerInfo timer, ExecutionContext context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ServiceFunction)} started!");

    await Service.Create();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to implement kind of lock ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it in Application Insight of your function app. First find the Application Insight of your function, then click "**Live metrics**" tab. You can find the detail logs in this page and check the status of your function running.
[image]

Comment: My aim was to create a service which will start after some other services finished. I know that is possible to check it in live metrics or in Monitor but I wanted to check the af function programatically.

Comment: @azuremycry I don't  think we can do it according to invocation id, because each triggered running instance have different invocation id. But not just one invocation id for the timer trigger function. Or you just want to know the status of each running instance ?

Comment: But if i store them in DB i will be able to download them and use.

Comment: @azuremycry Is it possible to create a sql table with a field for the status of your function. And add some lines of code(such as sql or other post operation) to modify the status. For example, at the beginning of your function execution, modify the status with `working`. At the end of your function execution, modify the status with `succeed`.... Then you just need to query the table for the status of your function.

Comment: Shen to be honest with you it is overengineering. I think exist kind of Azure Api that we can call using InvocationId to check if some of processes were finished.

Comment: @azuremycry Or you can also search the logs from application insight by query, you can do it by append the query(with invocation id) to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/get) api: `GET https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query?query={query}`